# How to import ExternalInterface once globally

Tags: javascript, flash, externalinterface

I am working on a Flash project (network speed test) and want to use ExternalInterface.call() at each step of the way to communicate to the HTML page on what step the Flash project is right now.

The problem is that on each and every scene's Actions, I have to import ExternalInterface like so `import flash.external.*;` and only then does this command work `ExternalInterface.call('console.log','Upload test FINISHED!');`

Can anyone show me how to import ExternalInterface **only once** globally?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot import it only once.  Well, that is only sort-of true.

You could create a singleton instance (or a static instance) elsewhere and use that, but instead of `import flash.external.ExternalInterface` everywhere, you would be doing something like `import myCustomClass` everywhere.

Since there is no gain in doing it that way, I would suggest you just import flash.external.ExternalInterface everywhere you need it.

Comment: Well, this is interesting. It just seemed redundant to import it in every Actions frame I use it. Do you know the reasoning behind this? Is it a security measure or something?

Comment: It's a scope thing, not a security thing.  You shouldn't need to import it on every frame (at least not that I remember), but different scenes would require it.\

Comment: No no, I meant import it in every "Actions KEYframe" (missed that, sorry). So, there's absolutely no way to declare that import on a global scope then?

Comment: I think if are able to restructure all your ExternalInterface calls in to one spot and have it as a singleton, there may be a benefit in that if anything goes wrong or you need to check input and output values or even just for testing, you can look for the logic in one spot instead of looking around for ExternalInterface calls scattered around your code.